# is it possible to specify the maximum amount of characters in a UITextField via IB

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have been wondering if there is a way of specifying the maximum of characters allowed in a UITextField via IB rather that having to override the UITextField methods.

I've successfully used

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

in the past, I just wondered if there is a tick box in IB I've missed.

Cheers

Comment: No there is nothing like that..You have to write a logic or use regular expression to limit your no. of characters in textfield programmatically only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IB (Interface Builder) doesn't do any logic for you. hence, there is no such functionality. This is done using the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) as you described yourself.

Comment: Do you happen to know why Apple has done it like this, instead of having some tickboxes or inputfields in IB for such simple settings?

Comment: No, but my guess would be because different people prefer different things. To just pick out some of those whould always leave one missing. 
Also, the delegate method would always be required by developers, yet the IB option not so much. I think most developers try to do without IB.